# 404 page not found when users try to access Azure Retrospective Board

Tags: azure-devops

[image: Error]I have added the users to the project and I am able to access the retrospective board, but my users cant. This is what they get when I send them the link. Any advise on how to send a link that opens up to the retrospective board - I have tried everything - this is so embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

404 error means that the URL is invalid. But from your description, the retrospective board indeed exists.

You can get the link via the option: **Copy Retrospective link** in Retrospective.

For example:

[image]

URL format Example:

```
https://dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_apps/hub/ms-devlabs.team-retrospectives.home?teamId=teamid&boardId=boardid
```

On the other hand, you can ask users to manually sign in Azure DevOps and check if they can see the retrospective board on Azure DevOps UI. In this case, you can make sure that they have enough permission to the retrospective board.

Comment: Hi Thanks, 

I tried giving out the retrospective link just as your picture shows, but that also did not work. In the end I was able to send a link that worked, but did not take the developer to the retro board... but it was the closest thing that worked. Its a shame to have spend all day just trying to get a link for this board. One funny thing I noticed seems like there is  a bug ---  I see a typo under General, Teams - instead of it reading add user it says "aad user"